# Python not working even after add to PATH

Tags: python, windows, cmd, environment-variables, python-3.8

```
C:\Users\HBP\Desktop\lecture3>python manage.py runserver

C:\Users\HBP\Desktop\lecture3>python manage.py runserver

C:\Users\HBP\Desktop\lecture3>python manage.py runserver

C:\Users\HBP\Desktop\lecture3>python
```

lines `python manage.py runserver` does nothing and the line `python` opens up the windows store.
I have already added to PATH during installation of python.

Python Ver : 3.8.5
OS : Windows 10 2002

Comment: Open settings->apps. Click on "app execution aliases", and disable the "python.exe" app installer alias that opens the store.

Comment: make sure you add it to the system path, not the user path.  Also make sure that manage.py is local to the python.exe , the current directory, or specify a full path to it.

Answer (score 0):

Command has been changed to just `py` instead of `python`